# Disadvantages of feeding infants oranges

Tags: feeding

My mother is feeding my 4 month year old baby sister oranges (because she likes and cries for oranges). We think this could have a disadvantage on her. What should we do?

Comment: How old is your baby sister, 4 months, a year and 4 months? "4 month year old" is confusing. Answers can be very different for different ages.

Comment: Also, is there a specific issue that you've heard or read about, related to oranges?